# Blocking equivalent of Java's Timer

Tags: java

Is there a blocking equivalent of the `java.util.Timer` class? I'm looking for the solution which will block the thread which creates the timer.

The following code is non-blocking and the `"After timer"` output is printed immediately.

```
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
    System.out.println("After timer");
```

What I want to achieve is `"After timer"` message printed only if timer has been canceled (and after is has been canceled).

Comment: If it's blocking, `"After timer"` will never print because the task is repeating.

Comment: [`Thread.sleep(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long))?

Comment: Your question may be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. It's possibly better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: @JacobG. In the snipped from the question it will never print, that's true. However if I add a call to `cancel` on the `Timer` reference, it will.

Comment: @Turing85 I find `Thread.sleep` hard to cancel/interrupt - you have to call `Thread.interrupt` from the same thread (as far as I understand) which is less handy than `Timer.cancel`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Good suggestion. I'm trying to write a code which: performs some action (let's say prints something to console), sleeps for *n* seconds and repeats this sequence. I want it to be blocking and has to be cancelable. I think accepted answer solves the problem, however the motivation of asking question was to find a standard Java API to do this (because I don't like inventing the wheel ;) ).

Comment: *"... you have to call Thread.interrupt from the same thread (as far as I understand)"* - A thread can interrupt any other thread.  (Indeed, if a thread could only interrupt itself, the interrupt mechanism would be pointless / useless.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside that this sounds like a strange thing to do ... and that blocking the thread is wasteful ...

I am unaware of a standard Java API that will do this.

Since `Timer` is not a `final` class, you could extend the class with overrides to the schedule methods to implement the blocking behavior, and overrides the cancel method with one that will (also) unblock any threads.  Something like this:

```
    public class MyTimer extends Timer {

        private final Object lock = new Object();
        private boolean canceled = false;

        @Override
        public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay) {
            synchronize (lock) {
                super.schedule(task, delay);
                while (!cancelled) {
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
        }

        // and more schedule overrides ...

        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            synchronize (lock) {
                super.cancel();
                canceled = true;
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that the behavior of `cancel()` is analogous to the standard `Timer::cancel` method.

- Scheduled tasks are canceled.
- If a task is executing it is allowed to complete.
- The cancel call does not wait for the task to complete
- After the `Timer` has been canceled, it will not accept any more tasks.

---

Finally, note that

```
new MyTimer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

(with a blocking schedule method) could not possibly unblock.  The `MyTimer` instance has to be published to a different thread so that that thread could call `cancel()` on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd prefer to have a 'waitable' TimerTask, one where you can choose to wait for it to be canceled, the following class introduces an `await()` method, which allows callers to wait for the timer task to be canceled.

```
abstract class WaitableTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override
    public boolean cancel() {
        boolean result = super.cancel();
        countDownLatch.countDown();
        return result;
    }

    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        countDownLatch.await();
    }
}
```

You would use it by doing something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final WaitableTimerTask waitableTimerTask = new WaitableTimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("TimerTask was run.");
        }
    };
    new Timer(true).schedule(waitableTimerTask, 1000, 1000);
    // Some other thread will need to cancel it.
    waitableTimerTask.await();
    System.out.println("TimerTask was canceled.");
}
```

That said, if the WaitableTimerTask is never canceled, the calls to `await()` will block forever.  This could be pretty confusing if the task was only scheduled to run once, as no one would expect to need to cancel it.